# Consuming WCF service in Com visible assembly

Tags: wcf, asp-classic, com+

I have to consume a WCF service hosted in Windows Service using a COM Visible assembly.

I have a WCF Service that is hosted in Windows Service, I have to consume the service in a COM Visible assembly, I have created a COM + application and added a service reference to it. Below is the `app.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="TcpEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
                    transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://serverMachine:9600/DocumentsWcfService/Tcp"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TcpEndpoint"
                contract="MysWcfService.IMysWcfService" name="TcpEndpoint" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I use this assembly in a classic ASP project and call the method that initializes the service I get the error as below. But when I refer the same WCF service in Console application, it works fine. Is there any specific changes required to consume in COM visible application.

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyWcfService.IMysWcfService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element

Comment: IF this is a DLL that is being called by a com component, you will not be able to rely on the app config, but will have to configure through code.

Comment: @PatFromCanada I am adding the WCF service reference direct to the Com component and using the COM component in ASP.If we have to configure through code, how can we use end point without hard coding address, please can you point to any resource Thank you.

Comment: Adrian's answer is one way to go, of course you could always create a text (XML) file and put an address in there, I have never had to deal with this particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM server don't read normal config files so you either need to do it via code or use the following trick:

(Your COM server must be an `.exe`)

1. Go to dcomcnfg and create a COM+ application
2. In the COM+ application there is a setting "Application Root Directory". Enter the folder where your .exe is located
3. Add your com object to the COM+ application
4. Create a file named `Application.manifest` in the folder. The file must contain:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

   <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" />`
5. Put your config file in the same folder. Note that the config file must have the exact name `Application.config`, not "myapp.exe.config"

Now the config file will work the same way as in your console application.

Comment: Thank you @adrian, but for my application we cannot have a COM server as a exe as we need to use that COM object in ASP application.

Comment: I did not create a .exe but for the COM project under Post build event command line added "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regsvcs  /appdir:$(ProjectDir) $(TargetFileName)" where ProjectDir is place that has the Application.config and Application.manifest

Comment: @ARV, did it work with .dll as well? (never tried it myself but I just assumed it didn't work since dll:s don't load config files). Why can't you use an .exe as COM server for ASP?

Answer (score 1):

Try to read configuration with

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "MysWcfService.dll.config";
configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Then you can try to read some wcf config sections and configure your host programmatically ([example](http://geekswithblogs.net/martinsj/archive/2012/10/14/hosting-and-consuming-wcf-services-without-configuration-files.aspx)):

```
    ServicesSection servicesSection = (ServicesSection)configuration.GetSection("system.serviceModel/services");
    ServiceEndpointElement endpoint = servicesSection.Services[0].Endpoints[0];
    //use endpoint.Address                                                                                            
    //use endpoint.Binding
    //use endpoint.Contract
```